# При удалении строки в DataGrid сбивается нумерация строк WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При удалении строки сбивается нумерация строк.

Разметка:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <NumerRow:NumerRow x:Key="NumerRow"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="199" 
              Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="297" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              EnableRowVirtualization="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="№"
                Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumerRow},
                    Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding first}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second" Binding="{Binding second}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Код C#:

```
public class Inform
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string second { get; set; }
}

public class NumerRow : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridRow row = value as DataGridRow;
        if (row.DataContext.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.NamedObject")
            return null;
        return row.GetIndex() + 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Inform> collection = new ObservableCollection<Inform>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, привязка никак не может узнать, что число строк изменилось и надо пересчитать их номера. Давайте это исправим, конвертер придется превратить в мультиконвертер, хотя фактически использоваться будет все равно один параметр:

```
public class NumerRow : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridRow row = values[0] as DataGridRow;
        if (row.DataContext?.GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.NamedObject") return null;
        return (row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Теперь переписываем немного разметку:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="№">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NumerRow}">
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}"/>
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="Items.Count"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Т.е. просто передаем вторым параметром текущее количество строк в DataGrid, как только оно меняется, привязка сработает и пересчитает все номера строк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]